# iTextSharp: Extra space between lines

Tags: itext

I am missing something in the following code and I get an extra space between lines in the output

```
        PdfContentByte ^cb = writer->DirectContent;
        ColumnText ^ct = gcnew ColumnText(cb);

        float gutter = 15;
        float colwidth = (document->Right - document->Left - gutter) / 2;

        array<float, 1>^ left = { document->Left + 133, document->Top - 35,
            document->Left + 133, document->Bottom };
        array<float, 1>^ right = { document->Left + colwidth, document->Top - 35,
            document->Left + colwidth, document->Bottom };

        for (int i = 0; i < m_strTestString->Length; i++)
        {
            Phrase ^Ps = gcnew Phrase(m_strTestString[i], font);
            Ps->SetLeading(0.0f, 0.6f);
            ct->AddText(Ps);
            ct->AddText(Chunk::NEWLINE);
        }
        ct->SetColumns(left, right);
        ct->Go();
```

The output is as below:

```
Client Name:sgsfg

Product:hjghj

Estimate#:354
```

I do not want the space between the above lines.

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated

One small clarification, if I do not add the

```
    ct->AddText(Chunk::NEWLINE);
```

the output shows up as:

```
   Client Name:sgsfgProduct:hjghjEstimate

   #:354
```

So I do not think my issue is because of the ct->AddText(Chunk::NEWLINE);

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that `ColumnText` knows two modes of operation, *text mode* and *composite mode*.

In *text mode* you add stuff with `AddText` and iText(Sharp) arranges the text pieces according to some `ColumnText` parameters.

In *composite mode* you add stuff using `AddElement` and iText(Sharp) arranges the elements according to the parameters they bring along.

*Text mode* has the advantage that it supports irregular (not necessarily rectangular) columns but essentially only supports text.

*Composite mode* has the advantage that it supports different kinds of elements (`Paragraph`, `List`, `PdfPTable`, and `Image` instances) but only supports rectangular columns.

---

In your case only text is added using only `setText` calls. Thus, you are in *text mode*. So the text is arranged according to `ColumnText` parameters. As you meanwhile (while I wrote my answer) have discovered yourself, you therefore have to use

```
ct->SetLeading(0.0f, 0.6f);
```

instead of

```
Ps->SetLeading(0.0f, 0.6f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

Instead of

```
Ps->SetLeading(0.0f, 0.6f);
```

I need to do

```
ct->SetLeading(0.0f, 0.6f);
```